# load_dotenv() не работает

Tags: python

Есть файл .env с таким содержанием:

```
BOT_TOKEN=1234e4321
URL_APPLES=https://...
URL_PEARS=https://...
```

И .py скрипт, который пытается получить переменную BOT_TOKEN и вывести её:

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()
BOT_TOKEN = os.getenv("BOT_TOKEN")
URL_APPLES = os.getenv("URL_APPLES")
URL_PEARS = os.getenv("URL_PEARS")

print(BOT_TOKEN)
```

Но он выводит None.

Естественно, python-dotenv установлен и оба файла находятся в одной директории. Но в чём тогда проблема?

Comment: А какая активная директория? Она такая же как папка с файлами? Попробуйте: `from pathlib import Path` `print(Path.cwd())`

Comment: Если используете IDE PyCharm выставьте для папки проекта Right Mouse CLick -> Mark Directory as -> Source Root

Answer (score 0):

Для папки проекта выставил Mark Directory as -> Source Root
За решение проблемы благодарность Serg Bocharov